# Cardinality of Union of $n$ sets

Tags: combinatorics

I have $n$ sets.Union of only $2$ sets is allowed.I need to find how many pairs are possible such that their union is Universe.

I tried it by every pair's union. But is there a way to determine it without trying every pair's union ?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question right: You have $n$ sets $A_1,\ldots, A_n$ and let $V=A_1\cup \ldots \cup A_n$. You want to find the number of pairs $(i,j)$, $1\le i<j\le n$, with $A_i\cup A_j=V$? Or in fact you want to knwo if there is an algorithm to count these that is faster than "brute force" (or faster than $O(n^2)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yeah you understood the question correctly and I want to know if there is an another way.

Answer (score 0):

In a way, you cannot avoid trying all pairs:
Assume you cannot actually inspect the contents of the $A_i$, but instead you only have an oracle that can tell you whether or not $A_i\cup A_j$ is the universe. Then you must test every single pair $(i,j)$ because for each subset $S\subseteq\{\,\{i,j\}\mid 1\le i<j\le n\,\}$, it is possible that $$A_i\cup A_j=V\iff \{i,j\}\notin S.$$
To see this, let $V=S$ and $A_i=\{\,s\in S\mid i\notin s\,\}$.
Then if $\{i,j\}\in S$, we have $\{i,j\}\notin A_i\cup A_j$ and so $A_i\cup A_j\ne S$; whereas for $\{i,j\}\notin S$, we have $A_i\cup A_j=S$ because for each $\{x,y\}\in S$ either $i\notin \{x,y\}$ or $j\notin\{x,y\}$.

Your mileage may vary if you can make advantage of details of $V$. For example, if en element $a$ is element of a handful of the $A_i$ only, you konw that at least one of the two sets must be in this handful ...